# android.speech.RecognitionService SecurityException with some 3rd-party speech recognizers

Tags: android, speech-recognition, device, securityexception, sfspeechrecognizer

We created an Android app which uses Google speech recognizer and we choose first ,in program, Google speech recognizer to use. Most devices work fine, and only few devices(MEIZU_M5, U78-E, Apollo Lite etc.) report below exceptions. It seems some conflicts with Mediatek's voicecommand? We found some other Mediatek's devices work fine. it's confusing.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.mediatek.voicecommand/.service.VoiceWakeupRecognitionService }
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1421)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1385)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:287)
```

To trace into the codes, the source codes only show up to ContextWrapper.java. How to let it show up to ContextImpl.java:1421?

By firebase log, we find it happens at many 3rd-party speech recognizers:

```
com.mediatek.voicecommand
com.htc.android.voicedictation
com.vlingo.midas
com.iflytek.speechcloud
com.iflytek.speechsuite
...
```

We've also tested some other 3rd-party speech recognizers working well. Are those speech recognizers,which caused exception, just used for system voice commands and not accessible to apps?

Any idea or experience is welcome.

Comment: What are the devices that give error?

Comment: some which use Mediatek's soc like MEIZU_M5, U78-E, Apollo Lite etc.

Comment: Edit this into the question body instead of commenting.

Comment: @svgrafov , add those devices in question body as your suggestion.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, we found the root cause from some information in Android Developers
[Services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services):

*However, you can declare the service as private in the manifest file and block access from other applications.*

These 3rd-party SpeechRecognizer services are private and can not be called by other apps. 
So, we just try-catch this exception and inform users to install Google App(Voice typing). Or you can exclude these unexpected SpeechRecognizer by just skipping them.